# Swift Authentication Challenge URLSession never called

Tags: swift, authentication, post, oauth, urlsession

I'm trying to access an API that's demanding username/password credentials. When debugging the code I noticed that after the let session variable is called, it goes straight into session.resume() and my urlSession method is never called to get user credentials from user input.

From what I read the completion handler will still call the delegate method specifically for auth challenges.

Running the app doesn't cause error but on the backend I'm getting this error and status code "401":

> Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300"

Here's the postReq function

```
func postRequest() {

    let parameters = ["grant_type=authorization_code&code=xyz"]
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "url to access") else {return}

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("xyz", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-Key")
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("Basic base64(xyz:xyz)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    guard let httpbody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else {return}
    request.httpBody = httpbody
    
    let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    session.resume()
}
```

delegate methods and helper method to get credentials straight from the swift doc

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    let authMethod = challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod
    guard authMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic else {
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
        return
    }
    //Call the completion handler
    guard let credential = credentialFromUI() else {
        completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        return
    }
    completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
}

func credentialFromUI() -> URLCredential? {
    guard let email = emailField!.text, !email.isEmpty,
        let password = passField!.text, !password.isEmpty else {
            return nil
    }
    return URLCredential(user: email, password: password, persistence: .forSession)
}
```

I'm also new to Swift and learning but feel like it's something trivial I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication challenge is not requested if you provide credentials in initial request, as

```
request.addValue("Basic base64(xyz:xyz)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

you should remove this line, and provide credentials via callback when asked.